# How to get number od days between few dates in symfony2 and return values to array

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to calculate number of days between few dates in my entity Symfony2. I have the entity with getDateFrom() and getDateTo(), which return DateTime. 
I write function :

```
public function getCountDays()
{

$total = array();

    foreach($this->getHolidays()  as $day)
    {
    $total[] =  (new DateTime($day->getDateTo()->format('Y-m-d')))->diff(new DateTime($day->getDateFrom()->format('Y-m-d')))->format('%a')+1 ;
    $sum =  array_sum($total);
    //print_r( $sum ) ;

    }

    return $sum;
}
```

Everything works, but this is not what I need. Function returns result  "3567" (between the first dates: period is 3 days, between second dates: period is 2 days, and between third dates: period is 1 day and between fourth dates period is 1 day). Calculation is good, but I need only return 7.
Any Ideas?

Comment: what are the exact dates we're talking about? From and To and the expected daycount for those ranges

Comment: The dates are: 1. DateFrom: 17-06-2015, DateTo: 18-06-2015, 2. DateFrom: 25-06-2015, DateTo: 27-06-2015, 3. DateFrom: 07-07-2015, DateTo: 07-07-2015, 4. DateFrom: 08-07-2015, DateTo: 08-07-2015.
But I need this for more dates than I have now. Dates come from Doctrine2 Entity

Comment: Your Answer throw exception: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given")" 
The problem is not in this total array, I get result for every index iteration in array_sum(), but I need only last iteration index.

Comment: my apologies, I did not understand the problem initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was easy to solve. Array_sum must be after foreach loop like below.

```
public function getCountDays()
{

$total = array();

foreach($this->getHolidays()  as $day)
{
$total[] =  (new DateTime($day->getDateTo()->format('Y-m-d')))->diff(new DateTime($day->getDateFrom()->format('Y-m-d')))->format('%a')+1 ;


}


$sum =  array_sum($total);

return $sum;
}
```

Thanx for help.